# Looking for documentation on DocuSign fields

Tags: docusignapi

Specifically, we get these errors: "Validation error: The 'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0:UserName' element is invalid ... The actual length is greater than the MaxLength value."  But I have not been able to find any documentation about what the maximum length of this field is.  I'd like to warn users of this value so they don't have to do trial and error to get it to work.  Specs on all the field limitations would be useful.  Or if the error message message said something along the line of "...is greater than the MaxLength value of 50."

Comment: Oh ok I see the UserName field is referenced, didn't notice that before.  Still in general you should try to provide more info on your questions including relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD provides this type of information, but I'm not sure whether or not DocuSign makes the XSD available for public consumption.  I'll leave it to @Ergin (DocuSign) to comment on that, and to provide the link to the XSD if appropriate.  Regarding specifically the **UserName** field, Max Length seems to be 100.

Answer (score 0):

The API Documentation has info on field limits.  You go the [DocuSign API Documentation page](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation), open either the Online SOAP API guide or the SOAP PDF guide, and do a search for CreateAndSendEnvelope.  See page 40 of the PDF guide for instance.

The guide lists the schema of the call, and if you read the descriptions they state the maximum limits.  For instance, it states the email subject is maximum 100 characters, email blurb is maximum 2000 characters, etc.

For envelope recipients you'll see a link that leads you to the Recipients schema (see page 53 of the PDF).  On there, you can see that UserName is maximum **100** characters.